# Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents not woking after get winId of a widget

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I am making a watermark overlay widget with Qt 5.15.2 on Windows.

The widget has a paintEvent override to draw watermark text onto the widget. And I set WA_TransparentForMouseEvents attribute for it so that I can click all the widgets covered by it.

Everything works nice until I called `winId()` method from a widget covered by this overlay.

Update:
According to @scheffs-cat 's answer, I set the window flags and it works. But when I moved my mouse to a `QPushButton` with it's cursor set to `Qt::PointingHandCursor`, my cursor has not changed. Also, my `QQuickWidget` under it doesn't work. It output a black screen, but i can interact with it.

WatermarkOverlay.h

```
#include <QWidget>

class WatermarkOverlay : public QWidget {
 public:
    explicit WatermarkOverlay(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~WatermarkOverlay() override;

 public:
    static QPixmap *getWatermarkPixmap();

 protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event) override;
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override;
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
};
```

WatermarkOverlay.cpp

```
#include "WatermarkOverlay.h"

#include <QEvent>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPainterPath>
#include <QDebug>

void initImage();
static QPixmap *s_pixmap;

WatermarkOverlay::WatermarkOverlay(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74298539/qtwa-transparentformouseevents-not-woking-after-get-winid-of-a-widget#comment131172159_74298539
    this->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::WindowTransparentForInput | Qt::WindowDoesNotAcceptFocus);
    this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_ShowWithoutActivating);

    this->setAttribute(Qt::WidgetAttribute::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);
    this->setAttribute(Qt::WidgetAttribute::WA_TranslucentBackground);

    parent->installEventFilter(this);
}

WatermarkOverlay::~WatermarkOverlay() {
    delete d;
}

QPixmap *WatermarkOverlay::getWatermarkPixmap() {
    WatermarkOverlayPrivate::initImage();
    return WatermarkOverlayPrivate::s_pixmap;
}

bool WatermarkOverlay::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event) {
    if (watched == this->parentWidget()) {
        switch (event->type()) {
            case QEvent::Resize:
            case QEvent::Show: {
                this->resize(this->parentWidget()->size());
                this->move(0, 0);
                this->raise();
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return QWidget::eventFilter(watched, event);
}

void WatermarkOverlay::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) {
    QPainter painter(this);
    auto pixMap = this->getWatermarkPixmap();
    painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, pixMap->width(), pixMap->height(), *pixMap);
}

void WatermarkOverlay::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
    qDebug() << __FUNCTION__;
}

bool WatermarkOverlayPrivate::isFirstInitImage = true;

QImage WatermarkOverlayPrivate::s_image;

QPixmap *WatermarkOverlayPrivate::s_pixmap = nullptr;

#include <QColor>

static QColor const TEXT_COLOR(255,255,255,60);
static QColor const OUTLINE_COLOR(0,0,0,60);

static auto constexpr WATERMARK_FONT_SIZE = 14;
static auto constexpr MAX_SCREEN_WIDTH = 3000;
static auto constexpr MAX_SCREEN_HEIGHT = 2000;
static auto constexpr WATERMARK_ROTATE = -20;
static auto constexpr MARGIN_X = 350;
static auto constexpr MARGIN_Y = 300;

static bool isFirstInitImage;
static QImage s_image;

void initImage() {
    if (!isFirstInitImage) return;
    isFirstInitImage = false;

    QFont font;
    font.setBold(true);

    s_image = QImage(MAX_SCREEN_WIDTH, MAX_SCREEN_HEIGHT, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    s_image.fill(Qt::transparent);

    QString const name = "This is watermark text";
    auto const fm = QFontMetrics(font);
    auto const w = fm.horizontalAdvance(name);
    auto const h = fm.height();
    auto const x_margin = w + MARGIN_X;
    auto const y_margin = h + MARGIN_Y;

    QPainter painter(&s_image);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);

    painter.setBrush(TEXT_COLOR);
    painter.setPen(OUTLINE_COLOR);
    painter.rotate(WATERMARK_ROTATE);

    QPainterPath path;
    for (int x = -MAX_SCREEN_WIDTH; x < MAX_SCREEN_WIDTH; x += x_margin) {
        for (int y = -MAX_SCREEN_HEIGHT; y < MAX_SCREEN_HEIGHT; y += y_margin) {
            path.addText(x, y, font, name);
        }
    }
    painter.drawPath(path);
    painter.end();

    s_pixmap = new QPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(s_image));
}
```

I override mousePressEvent for the overlay widget after that, and I found this event was triggered normally.

Comment: I used a `QLabel` as mouse pointer decoration for a hand-knitted drag manager. This is what I used: `_qLblIcon.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint
    | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint
    | Qt::WindowTransparentForInput | Qt::WindowDoesNotAcceptFocus);`
in addition to `_qLblIcon.setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);` and `_qLblIcon.setAttribute(Qt::WA_ShowWithoutActivating);`. It might be worth a try. (Not sure, where I found the settings or whether I used them on my own intuition.)

Comment: @scheffs-cat This works, I can interact with the widgets now. But the cursor not changed when I hovered my mouse to a button which I set it's cursor to `Qt::PointingHandCursor`. And my qml widget created with `QQuickWidget` outputs a black screen.